# Use key frame animation after a motion path

Tags: maya

I currently have a group of joints (bound to objects) moving along a motion path as desired. At the end of the path, I would like to switch to key frame animation. I tried moving the group and creating a key frame there a few frames after the motion path animation ends, but it disconnects from the motion path and stays in place, even after I go back to frame 1. How can I switch to key frame animation after the end of the motion path animation, but still keep it connected to the motion path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach one locator to the motion path. Create a second locator at the end of the motion path. Use a parent constraint for your group of joints where the two targets are the two locators. Set the weights to {1,0} whilst the motion path animation is running. Animate the weights so that they switch to {0,1} when you reach the end of the path. You are now free to keyframe the second locator.